# Create a non-linear structure in higher dimensional space in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I’m creating a non-linear structure in a 20-dim space. Right now I have code

```
    using Random

"`Uniform(0,b)`, with `0` excluded for sure, and we really mean it."
struct PositiveUniform{T}
    b::T
end


function Base.rand(rng::Random.AbstractRNG, pu::PositiveUniform)
    while true
        r = rand(rng)
        r > 0 && return r * pu.b
    end
end

    m = rand(PositiveUniform(20))
    mat_new = [cos(m),sin(m),cos(m),sin(m),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]'
for i in 1:84
    m = rand(PositiveUniform(20))
    vector = [cos(m),sin(m),cos(m),sin(m),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    mat_new = vcat(mat_new, vector')
end
mat_new'
```

And my mat_new' is like
[image]

I'm wondering is this matrix satisfying my expectation?

Comment: And which are your expectations? By the way, the probability of a continuous distribution to be a particular number (zero in this case) is zero, so yr code is a bit redundant...

Comment: My expectation is to create a 2-dim non-linear structure in a 20-dim space

Answer (score 0):

(edit:  I made a 2D structure 20 x 85, padding with zeros, since that is what was wanted, not a 20D array.)

```
const cols = 85
const rows = 20
const vec85 = rand(cols) .* rows
const mat2D = vcat(cos.(vec85)', sin.(vec85)', cos.(vec85)', sin.(vec85)', zeros(rows - 4, cols))

display(mat2D)
```

displays:

```
20×85 Matrix{Float64}:
-0.917208  -0.999591   -0.95458   -0.681959  0.999834   …  0.704834  0.961039  0.982991   0.967226   0.306118
0.398409   0.0286128  -0.297954  -0.731391  0.0182257     0.709372  0.276413  0.183653  -0.253917  -0.951993
-0.917208  -0.999591   -0.95458   -0.681959  0.999834      0.704834  0.961039  0.982991   0.967226   0.306118
0.398409   0.0286128  -0.297954  -0.731391  0.0182257     0.709372  0.276413  0.183653  -0.253917  -0.951993
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0        …  0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
⋮                                                      ⋱  ⋮
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0        …  0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0       0.0           0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        0.0
```

Note I kept your algorithm (perhaps not intended?) of setting the argument to sin and cos as nrows times rand(). If you want to pad the 2D array to contain more than just your matrix,  I would look at PaddedViews.jl or similar.

Comment: Why is the matrix not 20*85 dim?

Comment: I thought that the 20 was the number of dimensions? Do you also want it as the number of rows in the 2D structure?

Comment: Since my algorithm has to take in a matrix so I convert it as "m = mat20D[:,:]" and it gives me 4*85 matrix. I thought it is 4-dim?

Comment: Are you saying that you think that a matrix of 4 rows and 85 cols is 4-dimensional? Or are you saying that for you, the term "N-dim" means a 2-dimensional matrix with N rows?

Comment: I think a matrix of 4 rows and 85 cols is 4-dim.

Comment: The 'dim' function is used in Basic and R to get a vector containing the sizes of the array's dimensions. The 'ndim' function in Python's numpy returns the number of dimensions of an array. I do not know of any programming language that uses "4-dim" the  way you are doing. I wonder if you have come across misleading or mis-translated learning material?